# Unexpected token, expected "," in react-native expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am using RNPickerSelect and trying to put dynamic value to the dropdown list. Error i am getting as 'Unexpected token, expected ","'. Below is the script that i am using.

```
const RegisterScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

    const [value, setValue] = useState(undefined);

    useEffect(() => {
        var value = AsyncStorage.getItem('userData').then(
            (values) => {
                setValue(JSON.parse(values))
            });
    }, [])

    if (!value) {
        return null;
    }

    return (
        <Background>
            <View style={styles.mainPanel}>
                <View styles={styles.heading}>
                    <Header>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Dashboard')}><ImageBackground source={require('../assets/arrow_back.png')} style={styles.backButton}></ImageBackground></TouchableOpacity>
                Fund Transfer
                    </Header>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.mainviewBackground}>
                    <View>
                        <Text>Debit From Account :</Text>
                        <RNPickerSelect
                            onValueChange={(value) => console.log(value)}
                            items={[
                                { label: { value.accounts1 }, value: { value.accounts1 } }
                            ]}
                        />
                    </View>
```

Inside RNPickerSelectm items value I am trying to fetch the data from the values.

Comment: can you try to log AsyncStorage values?

Comment: @baymax yes, i did. It's printing . If i put {value.accounts1} next to Debit From Account it prints but not inside items label

Comment: please update your full code in a formatted style.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say when the shape of the values is not provided. But if they are objects, you could try:

```
items={[
{ label: ...value.accounts1, value: ...value.accounts1 }
]}
```

This will give you the same object in label and value. Or if you need specific values just:

```
items={[
{ label: value.accounts1.label, value: value.accounts1.value}
]}
```

For example. But it depends on what shape of the data you're expecting.